# Rails forms (checkboxes) - get a name attribute from an associated model without using f.label

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-i18n

I've been following this tutorial to set up a simple tagging system: http://www.sitepoint.com/save-multiple-checkbox-values-database-rails/

The only problem is that the 'name' on my Expertise model is being used as keys in .yml files (the tags will be translated into various languages).

The relationship of the Expertise model with the form's model (in this case, Teacher model) is a mutual 'has_and_belongs_to_many'

The form for the check boxes looks like this.

```
<%= form_for(@teacher, :html => {multipart: true, :class => "sky-form"}) do |f| %>
...

  <span>Areas of expertise:</span>
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes :expertise_ids, Expertise.all, :id, :name do |b| %>
    <label class="checkbox">
      <%= b.check_box %> <i></i> <%= b.label %>
    </label>
  <% end %>
...

<% end %>
```

Instead of b.label I want to do b.name (name is an attribute on the Expertise model) but when I do this, it pulls an error.

Any suggestions? I'm just trying to get the 'name' text of each instance of the Expertise model rather than it served in an entire html  element.

Comment: Could you share the error itself?

Comment: undefined method `name' for #<ActionView::Helpers::Tags::CollectionCheckBoxes::CheckBoxBuilder:0x007faa1b433970>
Application

Comment: I see, can you please also share the HTML, which is being generated with the above code and point out what is wrong with it?

Comment: the issue is b.label generates a`<label for="teacher_expertise_ids_8">Label Text</label>` element. I just want to generate the text of the name itself (here, "Label Text") without an accompanying <label> element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote from: http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_check_boxes

> There are also three special methods available: `object`, `text` and `value`.

I guess `b.text` or `b.value` is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you so much! I swear I looked over that exact page, but not thoroughly enough, evidently, as I completely missed that section. Thanks for your help!